# what is meaning of this error in mongodb error messageverbose?

Tags: database, mongodb, error-handling, server, nosql

I am a beginner of mongodb. I have installed and tried to run the server of mongodb with mongod command. but, it showing this error, what is  the meaning of this error?
(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.460+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":456}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.465+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.470+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"WT",       "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.481+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.486+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip  to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.494+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.499+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5853300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"current featureCompatibilityVersion value","attr":{"featureCompatibilityVersion":"6.0","context":"startup"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.504+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.508+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.701+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"C:/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.708+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled","oldState":"ConfigPreStart"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.710+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.719+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-10T17:20:12.723+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}